Active Directory user group not updating
I updated my AD user account with new groups, and my Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 systems aren't getting the new groups.
I have to clear the cache and restart SSSD to fix it.
Is there a more permanent solution?
Apr 01 13:01:34 krb5_child[1914548]: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_10715_XG6gbr)
Apr 01 13:01:25 krb5_child[1912964]: Preauthentication failed
Apr 01 13:01:25 krb5_child[1912964]: Preauthentication failed
Apr 01 13:01:25 krb5_child[1912964]: Preauthentication failed
Apr 01 10:15:53 sssd[780417]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Minor = Server not found in Kerberos database.
Apr 01 10:15:53 sssd[780412]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure
Apr 01 10:15:53 sssd[780412]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure
Apr 01 10:15:53 sssd[780407]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure
Apr 01 10:15:53 sssd[780407]: ; TSIG error with server: tsig verify failure

That's the error I was seeing on the journal.

Do the groups update if you wait 90 minutes?  That is the default cache timeout.  There are lots of cache configuration options in SSSD.  E.g. entry_cache_timeout.

doesn't seem to be
i'm gonna try to shorten the timeout
